# Set after tomorrow date to input as min date

Tags: javascript, date

This code works, but it sets today date

```
var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
document.getElementsByName("date")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
```

And I have tried this one, but it didn't worked

```
var today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate() + 2).toISOString().split('T')[0];
document.getElementsByName("date")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What exactly is the desired behavior?

Comment: I have <input type="date">. My first code sets to this input min value, so users can't choose any date before today(all date before today will be disabled). So I want change this min value to "after tomorrow date"(if get current date, min value should be '02-11-2017')

Answer (score 1):

First get the desired date and then convert it to `ISOString`like this:

```
var today = new Date();
    today = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + 2)).toISOString().split('T')[0];
    document.getElementsByName("date")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var today = new Date();
    today = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + 2)).toISOString().split('T')[0];
    document.getElementsByName("date")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a separate date from `today`, you need to create one with a second `new Date()` expression.

```js
var today = new Date();
var minDate = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + 2)).toISOString().split("T")[0];
console.log(minDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log( new Date(new Date().getTime() + 86400000).toISOString().split('T')[0] )
```

Comment: please tell us in a few words how and why you think this code you shared is answering the question.

Comment: @Andrew Ulianov code-only answers get flagged as low-effort, please provide a brief explanation of what your code does. Thanks!